# Amcharts5 XY-Charts show values under columns

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

**I have this XY-Chart:**

[image]

**I want to show the value under the XY-Chart:**

[image]

How can I do this? I have read the documentation, however I think it is to advanced (https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/).

**This is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Graph</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
<body>
<!-- Amcharts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
<!-- //Amcharts -->
<!-- Chart code :: graph_tasks_status_changes -->
    <script>
        am5.ready(function() {
            // Create root element
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
            var rootA = am5.Root.new("chartdiv_graph_tasks_status_changes");

            // Set themes
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
            rootA.setThemes([
              am5themes_Animated.new(rootA)
            ]);



            // Create chart
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
            var chartA = rootA.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(rootA, {
              panX: false,
              panY: false,
              layout: rootA.verticalLayout
            }));

            // Add legend
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/
            var legendA = chartA.children.push(
              am5.Legend.new(rootA, {
                centerX: am5.p50,
                x: am5.p50
              })
            );

            // Set data
            var data = [{
                  xlabelXYChart: "4",
                  value1: 200
                },{
                  xlabelXYChart: "5",
                  value1: 321
                },{
                  xlabelXYChart: "6",
                  value1: 385
                },{
                  xlabelXYChart: "7",
                  value1: 87
                }];

            // Create axes
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
            var xAxis = chartA.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(rootA, {
              categoryField: "xlabelXYChart",
              renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(rootA, {
                cellStartLocation: 0.1,
                cellEndLocation: 0.9
              }),
              tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(rootA, {}),
              stroke: am5.color(0xFFFFFF),
              visible: false

            }));

            xAxis.data.setAll(data);
            var yAxis = chartA.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(rootA, {
              renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(rootA, {}),
              stroke: am5.color(0xFFFFFF),
              visible: false
            }));

            // Add series
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
            function makeSeries(name, fieldName) {
              var series = chartA.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(rootA, {
                name: name,
                xAxis: xAxis,
                yAxis: yAxis,
                valueYField: fieldName,
                categoryXField: "xlabelXYChart"
              }));
              series.columns.template.setAll({
                tooltipText: "{categoryX} {name}: {valueY}",
                width: am5.percent(90),
                tooltipY: 0,
                fill: "#2b4356",
                stroke: "#67b7dc"
              });

            series.data.setAll(data);


            // Make stuff animate on load
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
              series.appear();
              series.bullets.push(function () {
                return am5.Bullet.new(rootA, {
                  locationY: 0,
                  sprite: am5.Label.new(rootA, {
                    text: "{valueY}",
                    fill: rootA.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
                    centerY: 0,
                    centerX: am5.p50,
                    populateText: true
                  })
                });
              });
              // legendA.data.push(series);
            }
            makeSeries("Status changes", "value1");

        }); // end am5.ready()
    </script>

    <div id="chartdiv_graph_tasks_status_changes" style="width: 100%;min-height: 150px;"></div>

<!-- //Chart code :: graph_tasks_status_changes -->
</body>
</html>
```

The color of the value has to be blue because I will show the graph on dark background.